# Turkey e-visa for Egyptian passport holder

Tags: turkey, egyptian-citizens, e-visas

I got the Turkey e-visa several times with my schengen visa. In the e-visa form there is a condition

> I have a round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines,
>   Onur Air or Egypt Air.

What if I am traveling from another country to Turkey or using another airlines like Nile Air form Egypt?

Answer (score 6):

I contacted the Airlines and they confirmed e-visa will work, thinking about it; visa on arrival is independent from the airline, so even e-visa says you have to fly with Turkish airlines or EgyptAir, I can get visa on arrival.

During check-in with NileAir I signed a form that they are not responsible about any issue happen due to visa; which means sometimes people face problem and it is not 100% guarantee it will work.

After arrival at Sabiha airport, passport control was easy and they accepted the e-visa.

I am sharing this with you so people can see real example not just references from internet.

Answer (score 4):

Then you're not eligible for e-visa, according to prerequisites which state it pretty clearly:

> You must meet all the requirements listed below in order to obtain an
>   e-Visa. Please confirm that you meet these criteria by clicking the
>   boxes next to them. If you do not meet **any of these requirements** and
>   you proceed with your application, **your e-Visa will be invalid**.
>
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at
>     least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
> - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
> - I have a round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines,    Onur Air or Egypt Air.
> - I hold a passport valid for at least 6 months from the date I intend    to enter Turkey.
> - I am below 20 or over 45 years old; or I have a valid Supporting    Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one
>     of the    Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not
>     accepted as    supporting documents.
> - I confirm that **I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above**.

Answer (score 2):

You would not be able to apply for an e-Visa. The reference is very specific to be eligible to apply electronically, as outlined by the information provided by the [Embassy of Turkey in Cairo](http://cairo.emb.mfa.gov.tr/ShowAnnouncement.aspx?ID=225850). It makes it very clear that you have to satisfy all of the conditions listed (emphasis mine):

> Checklist  for e-Visa:
>
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
>
>   - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
>   - I have a round-trip ticket with Turkish Airlines, Pegasus Airlines, Onur Air or Egypt Air.
>   - I hold a passport valid for at least 6 months from the date I intend to enter Turkey.
>   - I am below 20 or over 45 years old; or I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.
>   - ***I confirm that I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above***.

If you not eligible for an e-Visa, you must apply for a Regular (Sticker) Visa, through its [online Turkish visa application system](https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Visa/Index):

And those visa application requirements:

> 1. The validity of the passport should not be less than 6 months upon application.
> 2. Recent  bank statement covering the last 6 months.
> 3. Personal Photo 4x6 (white background).
> 4. A copy of the passport. Please also bring your original passport for the application.
> 5. Commercial registration or an HR letter from the employer stating the income.
> 6. The complete visa application form.
> 7. Hotel and flight reservation
> 8. Health insurance covering duration of stay in Turkey
>      9.The single entry visa fee is 470 Egyptian Pounds and the multiple entry visa fee is 1570 Egyptian Pounds.
> 9. The consular section has the right to add any further conditions according to the personal interview.